# Finding sub menu item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menuitem, toolstripdropdown

I've got a Windows Forms menu bar, with one menu item.  Below that is 1 Sub Item.

Let's say File → Open.

I'm trying to get a reference to the sub menu, but it is giving me a hard time.

```
ToolStripItem main = menuMain.Items["File"]; //This is fine.
ToolStripMenuItem sub =  main.DropDownItems(0); 
//Toolstrip item does not contain an extension for DropDownItems ??
```

How can I get a reference to the sub menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
var main = (ToolStripDropDownItem) menuMain.Items["File"];
var sub = main.DropDownItems[0]
```

`DropDownItems` property blongs to `ToolStripDropDownItem`  which is the base class for:

- `ToolStripMenuItem`
- `ToolStripDropDownButton`
- `ToolStripSplitButton`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ToolStripDropDownButton main = (ToolStripDropDownButton) toolStrip1.Items["File"];
ToolStripMenuItem sub = (ToolStripMenuItem) main.DropDownItems["FileOpen"];
```

You need to **cast the items to the right class**.
Please note that "File" and "FileOpen" are the names of the object.